# ¿como optimizar un bucle for?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, bucle-for, optimización

Estoy haciendo una interfaz grafica para la búsqueda de archivos, tengo mi código funcional, pero el problema es que este es muy lento al hacer la búsqueda del respectivo archivo, ¿alguna idea de como optimizar este código?

```
def agregar_menu(self):
    menubar1 = tk.Menu(self.ventana1)
    self.ventana1.geometry("400x400")
    self.ventana1.config(menu=menubar1)
    label1 = Label(self.ventana1, text = "Busqueda de documentos", font = ("Times", 14), padx = 10, pady = 10)
    label1.pack() 
    self.entry= tk.Entry(self.ventana1, width=45)
    self.entry.pack()
    self.entry.focus()
    self.ventana1.bind("<Return>", lambda x:searchfiles(self.entry.get(), 'C:\\'))
    
    self.lb = tk.Listbox(self.ventana1)        
    scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.ventana1, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
    self.lb = tk.Listbox(self.ventana1, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    scrollbar.config(command=self.lb.yview)
    scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y) 
    self.lb.pack(padx = 10, pady = 10, expand = YES, fill = "both")
    self.lb.bind("<Double-Button>", lambda x: open_file())

    #funcion de busqueda de archivos
    def searchfiles(extension='.txt', folder='C:\\'):
        "insertar documentos"
        for r, d, f in os.walk(folder): 
            for file in f:
                if file.endswith(extension):
                    self.lb.insert(0, r + "\\" + file)

    #funcion para abrir archivos
    def open_file():
        os.startfile(self.lb.get(self.lb.curselection()[0]))
```

Comment: si tan solo estas recorriendo unos pocos archivos (algo de 10 o 30) el ciclo `for` no es el problema, pero si estas recorriendo 10 000 archivos entonces tendrías que buscar una forma de limitar la búsqueda, por ejemplo haciéndolo hasta un rango de fecha

Comment: la aplicación esta diseñada para recorrer todos las carpetas de tu equipo y según eso, devuelva el archivo que estés buscando, por esto puede variar la cantidad que sea devuelta. pero en si, se podría decir que si busca entre bastantes archivos, 300 como mínimo.

Comment: entonces no hay forma de optimizarlo, pero puedes usar una comprensión de lista anidada que es más rápida que un ciclo `for` convencional

Comment: y como sería eso? soy completamente nueva en programación y con lo poco que he aprendido he logrado hacer este programa, me sería de mucha ayuda si me explicas, por favor.

Comment: sería algo así `self.lb += [file for r, d, f in os.walk("../") for file in f  if file.endswith(".txt")]`

Comment: seré un tanto cansona en el tema, pero me aparece el siguiente error utilizando tu método: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'Listbox' and 'list'

Comment: bueno no sé mucho de tkinter y se me pasó eso, pero te explico. lo que retorna `[file for r, d, f in os.walk("../") for file in f  if file.endswith(".txt")]` es una lista de todos los archivos que cumple la condición, luego debes de buscar la forma de agregarlo a tu Listbox, podrías probar con `[self.lb.insert(0,file) for r, d, f in os.walk("../") for file in f  if file.endswith(".txt")] `

Comment: Me sirvió mucho, gracias

Comment: Recuerda que si has hallado la solución puedes agregar una respuesta para así ayudar a otros con un problema similar :D